# What was the function to decode special characters like \n to their representatives?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically user provides input for my script using shell arguments, an example of user input is like this:

> Kek kek\nkek\tkek\x43

Upon receiving the input, javascript shows that my parameter is basically defined like this:

```
var parameter="Kek kek\\nkek\\tkek\\x43";
```

The above string basically has slashes escaped, instead of converting them into the needed characters.

So what I'm trying to do is to convert my `parameter` variable into a `desired_outcome` variable, which would look like this:

```
var desired_outcome="Kek kek\nkek\tkek\x43";
```

Subsequently, if printed out the result should output:

```
Kek kek
kek     kekC
```

So what was the right function to convert one into another?

Comment: There's no special function for that, just add the string to a container.

Comment: Output to HTML?

Comment: `node script.js delimiter="\t"` is not JavaScript, that’s shell code, so `"\t"` isn’t a JavaScript string. In shell, however, you can try `node script.js delimiter=$'\t'` instead.

Comment: I'm calling my script like ```node script.js delimiter="\t"``` (from windwos shell) process.argv shows ```delimiter=\\t``` in cosole, think I just need to strip slashes (accidentally deleted my comment).

Comment: Duplicate of [Bash: how to pass arguments with special characters like \t](/q/25027915/4642212): _“\[Y\]ou can pass an actual tab with `my_grep $'hello\tworld'`.”_, or, in your example, `node script.js $'delimiter=\t'` or just `$'\t'`, depending on how you want to use this argument.

Comment: It's all very fine but doesn't seem to work for windows shell though.

Comment: @Anonymous Then use a JSON format: `node script.js '{ "delimiter": "\t" }'`. Then `JSON.parse(process.argv[2]).delimiter`. However, `\x`… and `\u{`…`}` syntax is not supported there. Your example string would need to be rewritten as `"Kek kek\nkek\tkek\u0043"`.

Comment: I think we are getting close, please see the last edit, if it's possible to convert the string without json format, because 1) its verbose and 2) ```process.argv``` will break it into ```'{```, ```delimiter:```, ```\\t```, ```}'```.

Comment: @Anonymous Normally, `'{ "delimiter": "\t" }'` should be a single shell parameter, if the shell properly supports quoting. This isn’t a problem anyway; you can just as well use `{"delimiter":"\t"}` as the parameter.

Comment: Please see the whole question has been edited again to make it clear what the question was.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I've totally misunderstood your comment, removed the result of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem, as according to the specification:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

```
const decode_string = input => "nrtbfv0".split('')
    .map((x,i)=>[new RegExp(`\\\\${x}`,'g'),"\n\r\t\b\f\v\0".split('')[i]])
    .concat([[/\\[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/g,(_,hh)=>String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hh,16))]])
    .reduce((out,m)=>out.replace(m[0],m[1]),input);
```

*Explanation:*

I have built a 2D array with regex and corresponding replacements. The dynamically built regex contain an actual slash character `\` + one of the letters where the replacements correspond to special characters. Next I've added a regex for the ASCII hexadecimal characters, where the replacement is a function that uses `String.fromCharCode()` conversion. Finally, it reduces the input, running all of them together.

*Usage:*

```
var parameter="Kek kek\\nkek\\tkek\\x43";
var desired_outcome = decode_string(parameter);
```

*Notes:*

Double slashes don't need to be decoded because they are already escaped.
Quotes, both double and single, don't have to be escaped either, because they are being escaped on a shell level.